# Unable to detect end of file when reading from a disk device in python

Tags: python, windows, binary, device, eof

I am using python 3.3 32 bit on windows 8. I want to read binary sectors from a physical disk. I am able to open, seek, read, tell from the device but end of file doesn't produce an empty read result, it throws a Permission exception (33). I am also unable to use seek relative to the end, e.g.  seek(-512,os.SEEK_END). Any use of SEEK_END or 2 throws Invalid Argument.

I'd really prefer not to have to use permission exceptions to detect eof, since when reading devices real permission errors are possible, and users need to be warned of this failure.

I would welcome any hints on what is going wrong here, or alternative ways of detecting eof.

Code example follows, the device is a 1GBit USB. The seek/tell/prints are to show that reading is normal until eof.

code:

```
device = r'\\.\PhysicalDrive2'  
disk = open(device,'rb')  
disk.seek(1994231*512)  
sector = disk.read(512)  
while sector!="":  
    sector = disk.read(512)  
    print(disk.tell())
```

output:

> 1021047296 1021047808 1021048320 1021048832 1021049344 1021049856
>   1021050368 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\Development\eclipse\test\test.py", line 25, in 
>       sector = disk.read(512) IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: This is a new field of use for a text-processing script tool. I can't say I approve, but at least it's not PHP. Any comments as to how you're going to output the disk image/results, and why?

Answer (score 0):

You get permission denied when it cannot read the entire chunk of data at the end of the drive (or file).  This is an example.  ALSO, be sure to run Python as Administrator. (Using Windows 10 and Python 3.8.2)

```
import re
import time

starttime = time.time()

stuff = []
chunk = 512
with open(r"\\.\physicaldrive11",'rb') as file_obj: #Physical Drive
#with open("test.bin",'rb') as file_obj: #File
    while True:
        try:
            data=file_obj.read(chunk)
            #do cool stuff and append to list
            #stuff.append(cool stuff)
            #print (stuff)
            print (data) # if you want to see what it is doing... use a small drive, unless you want to wait forever  :-)
            
            if data == b'':
                file_obj.close()
                break

        except PermissionError:
            chunk = chunk-1
            print ("Trying smaller chunk",chunk)
            continue

endtime = time.time()
timerun = endtime - starttime
print (timerun)
```